# How to execute a stored procedure using OCI8 in PHP

Tags: php, oracle, stored-procedures, oci8

Can someone help me on how to call the stored procedure in oracle by php?
I have the sample of stored procedure

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE view_institution(
       c_dbuser OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)
IS
BEGIN
  OPEN c_dbuser FOR
  SELECT * FROM institution;
END;
```

the above stored procedure named view_instituion used to display all record on table institution. Can someone teach me to call the above stored procedure in php. Im new on playing with stored procedure

thanks

Comment: What is PDO? im new :(

Comment: PDO Basics : http://bit.ly/pdobasics

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**If you use the PDO engine**

```
/* Define output */
$output = "";    

/* The call */
$stmt= $pdo->prepare("CALL view_institution(?)");

/* Binding Parameters */
$stmt->bindParam($parameter1, $output);
 
/* Execture Query */
$stmt->execute();

/* Get output on the screeen */
print_r($output, true);
```

**If you use oci**

```
/* The call */
$sql = "CALL view_institution(:parameter)";

/* Parse connection and sql */
$stmt= oci_parse($conn, $sql);
 
/* Binding Parameters */
oci_bind_by_name($stmt, ':parameter', $yourparameter) ;

/* Execute */
$res = oci_execute($stmt);

/* Get the output on the screen */
print_r($res, true);
```

Comment: ohh.. i am using oci.. is that the same?

Comment: <?php

$objConnect = oci_connect("ccc","rrr","ff");?>

that is my example of connection to oracle db..

Comment: Made an example for OCI. I did not used it for a long time, but I think its right like this.

Comment: @user2234937 oci is oracle specific, PDO is for multiple database types

Comment: Thanks.. for my cases, what is the :parameter?

Comment: If you want to send a parameter with the stored procedure, you need to send parameter with it. For example `CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE HelloWorld(param1 IN VARCHAR2)` ect ect

Comment: is it the same with my stored procedure like above?

Comment: I your case you need to send `c_dbuser` with it.

Comment: Can u check my code? I edit ur previous answer..

Comment: Warning: oci_execute() [function.oci-execute]: ORA-06553: PLS-306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'VIEW_INSTITUTION' in C:\xampp\htdocs\tutorialphpoci\sp.php on line 20

Comment: You are doing `OPEN c_dbuser FOR SELECT * FROM institution;` in your procedure. What is c_duser in your case?

Comment: Do u have an idea on change it?

Comment: i used this to display all record on institution table..

Comment: Change the procedure to this: http://www.sourcepod.com/fzyujl18-18137

Comment: what is the parameter?

Comment: You can remove the parameter and the binding.

Comment: Check: http://www.sourcepod.com/nzptew05-18138

Comment: i cant create the procedure on oracle because : ERROR at line 1: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol ")" when expecting one of the following:

Comment: This error appear : ERROR at line 4: PLS-00428: an INTO clause is expected in this SELECT statement

Comment: please read this: http://www.mkyong.com/oracle/oracle-stored-procedures-hello-world-examples/